# PHP Curl Return Boolean Value

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code that returns a bunch of results back from an API, everything inside "" works but the Boolean values that dont have "" dont return, is there something im missing from code for this??

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "URL",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: KEY"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$json_a2 = json_decode($response, true);
```

What is been returned back from the API is

```
"VehicleRegistration": {
        "DateOfLastUpdate": "2014-12-19T00:00:00",
        "Colour": "BLACK",
        "AbiBrokerNetCode": null,
        "EngineCapacity": "1598",
        "TransmissionCode": "M",
        "DtpMakeCode": "DF",
        "Exported": false,
        "YearOfManufacture": "2014",
        "WheelPlan": null,
        "DateExported": null,
        "Scrapped": false,
}
```

The false is not showing when i return the results.

Comment: The trailing comma after `false` makes this invalid JSON. Can you post EXACTLY what you're getting back from the API?

Comment: `false` and `true` without quotes is perfectly valid.

Comment: My crystal balls suggests you've decoded JSON and tried to `echo` boolean values, which of course cast as string as `'1'`  and `''` (empty string) because that's how PHP is.

Comment: Use `var_dump($json_a2)` to see everything that's returned.

Answer (score 0):

The false will not show as php will always display a boolean false value as empty string.

In PHP false, null, empty string, and 0 will all equal false.

If you need to check to see if your var is really false and not any other then use:

```
$my_var === false;
```

or

```
false === $my_var;
```

*Note triple equals*